# Quicksort out of order execution

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement the Quicksort algorithm with the Lomuto partition scheme. Had some tad bugs here and there but right now it sorts the array.

The input is: 3 4 15 1.

The problem is that it doesn't terminate and the even weirder effect is that code which looks like that:

```
public void quickSort(int start, int end) {
    System.out.println("Quicksorting...\n Start: " + start + " End: " + end);
    System.out.println("Is start<end: " + (start < end ? "true" : "false") + "!!!!!!!!!!");
    while (start < end) {
        System.out.println("In case: (start:end) = " + start + "; " + end);
        partitionPoint = partition_lomuto(start, end);
        System.out.println("partition point: " + partitionPoint);
        System.out.println("\n\nCalling quickSort left...");
        quickSort(start, partitionPoint);   // On left of the pivot.
        System.out.println("\n\nCalling quickSort right...");
        quickSort(partitionPoint+1, end);   // On right of the pivot.
    }
    System.out.println("Cancel qs call");
}
```

Gets executed (seemingly) like so:

```
Calling quickSort right...
Quicksorting...
Start: 3 End: 3
Is start<end: false!!!!!!!!!!
Cancel qs call
In case: (start:end) = 2; 3  // UNEXPLAINABLE BEHAVIOUR LINE
1 3 15 4 
partition point: 2
```

In my opinion anything under the "UNEXPLAINABLE BEHAVIOUR LINE" shouldn't exist, or at least the log should show that quicksort has been called with another 'start' and 'end' indices. Furthermore, as you can see at that point it starts shuffling around the values of the already sorted array and really doesn't terminate.

I run that on Linux.

I counted the number of left-partition sorts and the right-side partition sorts and they're equal in number. 
All I am looking for is an explanation of how that above can happen.

Comment: Why is there a `while` loop anyway? Shouldn't that be an `if`? When the recursive call terminates with `cancel qs call`, the calling function returns to the beginning of the `while` and therefore prints `In case: ...`. And since you never change `start` or `end`, this runs indefinitely.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thank you very much! Missed such an obvious bit!!! Thank you very much! If you want write an answer so that I can give you a point there.